# knockout.js using the mapping plugin

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am a newbie with knockout.js and want to start using the automatic mapping plugin. How can I convert this manually mapped code to use the mapping plugin?

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/jWTtb/6/

```
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function (firstName, lastName) {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);

    self.loadJson = function () {
        $.getJSON("http://echo.jsontest.com/firstName/Stuart/lastName/Little",
        function (data) {
            self.firstName(data.firstName);
            self.lastName(data.lastName);
        });
        return true;
    };

};
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

Comment: well firstly you will want to state how you are going to be sending the model data to the mapping plugin, basically what form it will take and how that information gets there. The mapping plugin is used to allow mapping of dynamic models retrieved from a server to a ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am not very experienced with Knockout myself, but from the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) it looks like all you should have to do is:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

In your case, it would look more like this:

```
var viewModel;
$.getJSON("http://echo.jsontest.com/firstName/Stuart/lastName/Little", function (data) {
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

I tested it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWTtb/8/).

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. Can you make a jsfiddle to show me?

Comment: Do you know what doesn't work? Are there errors in the console of your browser?

Comment: Um, duh! It finally occurred to me. I said `applyBindings` before the JSON was returned. I fixed the answer. It's working for me now in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWTtb/8/).

Comment: Wow, that is so much simpler. I think this is my new preferred method.